# Logging which Spring AOP

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop, servlet-filters

I am trying to add log for my api but I have a question in my code about aspects.

My project has the follwing structure , the classical structure controller and service

```
com.surname.apiproject.sports
com.surname.apiproject.sports.SportController
com.surname.apiproject.sports.SportService
com.surname.apiproject.users
com.surname.apiproject.users.UserController
com.surname.apiproject.users.UserService
```

I have the following Spring AOP.

```
@Around("execution(* com.fernandez.api.project.*.*(..))")
    public void time(final ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        DateFormat df = DateFormat.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        String dateString = format.format(new Date());      
        String random = randomUUID();
        Object value;
        try {
            value = proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            throw throwable;
        } finally {
            long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
            log.info("--- UUID3 --- : " + random + " --- Fecha ---" + dateString +" --- Camino --- :"+ proceedingJoinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringType().getSimpleName() +  " --Name --- " +proceedingJoinPoint.getSignature().getName());
        }

    }
```

When I try to execute the petition I don't see anything about petiion but If I use Filters I could see the petition so I don't know which is the best option if use SpringAOP or Filters for logging.

Regards

Comment: Petition? Filters?

Comment: @daniu "petition" = "request", "filters" = `javax.servlet.Filter`

Comment: Your aspect advice returns `void`, i.e. it will not match any methods returning anything other than `void`. To make it work more generally, make the method return `Object` and also make sure to actually return the result of `proceed()` or whatever alternative result you want to be returned. Also, if your package structure is nested and not just one level, better use `..*` instead of `*.*`, e.g. `execution(* com.fernandez.api.project..*(..))`. If it still does not work like this, your AOP configuration is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your logging is in regard to servlet API requests, then use a `Filter`. Otherwise use AOP. You should also check whether the logger is enabled before bothering to compute the time taken, and use the log API's formatting instead of string concatenation.

If the former, Spring Boot already [configures a metrics filter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-metrics.html#production-ready-metrics-meter) to gather API performance data. You may find that is already sufficient.

For more advanced performance tracing, you can use an APM agent like [Elastic's](https://www.elastic.co/solutions/apm) or [DataDog's](https://www.datadoghq.com/apm/).

---

Example for the first option

```java
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class PerformanceLogFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMAT 
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS");

    @Override
    protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return !logger.isInfoEnabled();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            FilterChain filterChain
    ) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        Instant start = Instant.now();
        try {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        } finally {
            // N.B. commons-logging, not slf4j
            logger.info(String.format("%s %s: %.1f ms",
                    start.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).format(FORMAT),
                    request.getRequestURI(),
                    start.until(Instant.now(), ChronoUnit.MICROS) * 1e-3
            ));
        }
    }
```